# Accessing the databound event of a databound control within a formview

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know if you can access the databound event from a databound, say, dropdownlist that is within a FormView EditItemTemplate?

For example, say you have a member update form, and within the EditItemTemplate you have a dropdownlist that binds the CityID to a list of Cities.  So I'd like to tap into the databound event for that control in the formview and add a value to the cities.

Also, I know there are other ways to handle the situation.  I'm not looking for an alternate solution to this problem, I'd like to know if anyone has been able to do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!  Here's a way I've done it before.  Once your `FormView` loads, you can find the DataBound control using the `FindControl` method:

```
DropDownList myDDL = (DropDownList)FormView1.Findcontrol("myDDL");
```

Then, you can use the `+=` syntax to add the event handler method you've written:

```
myDDL.DataBound += myDDL_DataBound;
```

Then, whenever you call `myDDL.DataBind()`, the `myDDL_DataBound` method will be executed.

Edit: Just to be clear - you say "Access the databound event".  That means the method I mentioned (`myDDL_DataBound`) needs to look something like this:

```
protected void myDDL_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //The code you want to execute for the embeded, databound control goes here.
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot that!  5 years late is better than never.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do this:
Simply add the OnDataBound parameter into the DropDownList
Then write your function from the code behind

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="MyDDL" runat="server" OnDataBound="myDDL_DataBound" ... />
```